# Calculating the gradient used by the Jacobian-based Dataset Augmentation in Keras

Tags: keras, gradient

I am trying to understand my mistake when calculating the sign of the gradient used by the jacobian-based dataset augmentation published in https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02697

> " the sign of the Jacobian matrix dimension corresponding to the label assigned to input $\vec{x}$ by the oracle $\tilde{O}$: $sgn(J_F(\vec{x})[\tilde{O}(\vec{x})])$ "

For the calculation you can ignore the oracle O and simply treat it like a classification result Y.

As I understand the term correctly I have to calculate the gradient of the function that the neural network has learned w.r.t the inputs and then evaluate it with the current input vector x. The result should then be an array which contains the gradients for the input vector for each class.

For demonstration purposes I trained a keras model with the Iris data set according to https://www.kaggle.com/lavajiit/deep-learning-iris-dataset-keras/notebook
and then calculated the sign of the gradients in the following way:

```
out = model.output
in = model.input
gradients = k.gradients(out,in)[0]
session = k.get_session()
session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
evaluated_gradients = session.run([tf.sign(gradients)], feed_dict={model.input: X_train})[0]
```

Unfortunately I do not get the desired results:

[image]

As you can see it only contains the gradients for the 4 features of the 120 input vectors, hence the shape (120,4) but it should calculate them for each class.
E.g 3 x (120,4)

[image]

Additionally the gradients are mostly zero but in between there are some rows that seem to be correctly calculated.

I very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient needs to be computed for each of the 3 outputs separately:

```
tf.gradients(out[:, class_i], in)
```

[image]